# A same folder zipped once using phpzip and once using PclZip, the checksums of the 2 files should be differents?

Tags: zip, md5, checksum, integrity, pclzip

Below is my question :

1. Zip a folder 'F' using phpzip  => checksum MD5 of the zip file = X
2. Zip the same folder 'F' using PlcZip  => checksum MD5 of the zip    file = Y   (X # Y)

is this normal ?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal, even if you use the same Zipping library the hashes may not be always the same
if a single bit changed in the zip file due to timestamps or files order the whole hash will be different